# Validate a nested component in a fieldArray using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, react-hook-form

I have a list consisting of custom components (`MaterialBar`) containing a couple of fields:

[image]

I do a bulk update/save, so when I hit the "Save materials"-button, all the new materials should be created (if the required fields have a value) and the current ones should be updated, if they have changed. I am just unsure how I get the state of the nested `MaterialBar`s (`isValid` for the new items and `isDirty` for the existing ones). How I do it right now:

**Parent/useFieldArray:**

```js
export interface ProjectMaterialFormValues {
    materialBars: IMaterialBar[];
}

function ProjectMaterials({
  project,
  attachMaterial,
  detachMaterial,
}: ProjectMaterialsProps) {
  const { control, handleSubmit, formState } =
    useForm<ProjectMaterialFormValues>({
      defaultValues: { materialBars: projectMaterialsForProject(project) },
      mode: "onChange",
    });

  const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "materialBars",
  });

  return (
    <>
      {fields.map(({ id }, index) => (
        <MaterialBar
          key={id}
          index={index}
          onDelete={(projectMaterialId) =>
            setMaterialToDelete(projectMaterialId)
          }
          control={control}
        />
      ))}

      <ButtonsContainer>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => navigate(routes.INDEX)}>
          {texts.HOME_RETURN_HOME}
        </Button>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={addMaterial}>
          {texts.BUTTON_ADD_NEW_MATERIALS}
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          disabled={isSaving}
          onClick={handleSubmit(saveAllMaterials)}
        >
          {texts.BUTTON_SAVE_MATERIALS}
        </Button>
      </ButtonsContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

Each `MaterialBar` is then registered though a [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller):

**MaterialBar:**

```js
interface MaterialBarProps {
  index: number;
  onDelete: (id: number) => void;
  control: Control<ProjectMaterialFormValues>;
}

function MaterialBar({ index, onDelete, control }: MaterialBarProps) {
  const { materials } = useAllMaterials();

  return (
    <Container>
      <FormField>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name={`materialBars.${index}.materialId`}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <Dropdown
              label="Material"
              items={materials}
              selectedItem={value}
              onSelect={onChange}
            />
          )}
        />
      </FormField>
      // the other fields
      <FormField>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name={`materialBars.${index}.amount`}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <TextField
              label="Amount"
              type="number"
              value={value}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          )}
        />
      </FormField>
      <Button onClick={handleDelete}>
        <img src={remove} alt="delete" />
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Doing it like this, I cannot get the state of each component which means that I do all the vaidation manually right now:

```js
const saveAllMaterials: SubmitHandler<ProjectMaterialFormValues> = ({
  materialBars,
}) => {
  materialBars.forEach((newMaterial, index) => {
    if (newMaterial.projectMaterialId) {
      if (formState.dirtyFields.materialBars) {
        const dirtyIndexes = Object.keys(
          dirtyFields.materialBars as unknown as string
        );
        if (dirtyIndexes.includes(index.toString())) {
          // The API does not support update. Instead the material must
          // be deleted and a new one is created with the updated values
          detachMaterial(fields[index].materialId!);
          attachMaterial(newMaterial);
        }
      }
    } else if (
      // Would be nice if I can do something like "newMaterial.isValid"
      !newMaterial.projectMaterialId &&
      newMaterial.materialId &&
      newMaterial.typeId &&
      newMaterial.amount
    ) {
      attachMaterial(newMaterial);
    }
  });
};
```

This seems really unnecessary. Is there a way where I can access the state of of the child when I iterate through all the children in the `fieldArray`, so I don't have to do the verbose calculations?
I was thinking that perhaps I need to have another `useForm` in the `MaterialBar`, but how do I pass the state to the parent upon saving?

Comment: What are you using to validate your inputs, the ones not in the filed array? If they are all of the inputs the form have then are you in the mood for using yup validation to intelligently validate your dynamic inputs? If answer it's true then I would show how to validate dynamic inputs generated by the useArrayField of react-hook-form

Comment: Right now I use react-hook-form's own validation rules, but I already planned to use yup, so if you can make an example, that would be great.

Comment: Check the snippet, any doubt don't hesitate to ask

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá I haven't forgotten you, I am just on a summer break from this project. I will test it as soon as I start working on it again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
import {Controller, useForm} from 'react-hook-form'
import {yupResolver} from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from 'yup'

// validation rules
const validation = yup.object({
    //... other validations
    // assert your field is an array of object with the shape you want
    fieldArrayName: yup.lazy(() => yup.array().of(yup.object({
        prop1: yup.string().required(), // validate each object's entry
        prop2: yup.number().required()  // independently
    })))
})


const {control} = useForm(({
    // ...
    resolver: yupResolver(validation) // pass the validation rules to the form
}))

// render array field
{
    fields.map(
        ({id}, index) => (
            <div key={id}>
                <Controller
                    // the name of the input should be prefixed with the
                    // array field's name(.) the current index (.)
                    name={`fieldArrayName.${index}.prop1`}
                    control={control}
                    render={({field, fieldStatus: {invalid, error}}) => (
                        <>
                        <input  {...field}/>
                        {invalid && <p>{error.message}</p>}
                        </p>
                    )}/>
                <Controller
                    name={`fieldArrayName.${index}.prop2`}
                    control={control}
                    render={({field, fieldStatus: {invalid, error}}) => (
                        <>
                        <input  {...field}/>
                        {invalid && <p>{error.message}</p>}
                        </p>
                    )}/>
                ...
            </div>
        ))
}
```

Comment: `render={({field, fieldStatus: {invalid, error}}) => ( ... )}` this line should be corrected as  `render={({field, fieldState: {invalid, error}}) => ( ... )}` . It is *fieldState* not *fieldStatus*